# Vim plugin which uses the compiler Include to jump to function, and show prototype and auto-compilation

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

In vim on Linux mainly, if I've a c or c++ source file which includes many other header files.

Is there any plugin available which can use the compiler Include (-I) and shows the syntax of the function on which the cursor or something like jump to definition.

I know about ctag, but is there anything more advance something like Visual Studio on windows.

Comment: Use an IDE if you want IDE features. Not a text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) and [ClangComplete](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete).  These both use libclang to handle the completion.

Comment: Thanks GWW! I hope this will be suffice, once I get the setup done correctly.

Comment: @dearvivekkumar: I have found that YouCompleteMe is a bit easier to install and get working.  I would try that first.

Comment: ok... I'll go first with YouCompleteMe. Thanks for sharing your experience

Comment: tried installing YouCompleteMe on windows... Not success so far! Getting runtime error when launching gvim "As virtual function call .."

Comment: @dearvivekkumar: Oh, sorry I didn't realize you were using Windows.  You may have a rough time getting those plugins to work.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for is the whole purpose of ctags. If you haven't done that yet, you should read `:help tags` and `:help ctags`. The `:tselect` command may be what you are looking for.

Cscope is another slightly more advanced solution (it does "jump to usage" too). See `:help cscope` for more information.

That said, Vim has built-in "include-search": `:help include-search` has this nice little mapping example:

```
:map <F4> [I:let nr = input("Which one: ")<Bar>exe "normal " . nr ."[\t"<CR>
```